# Showing only part of an article when listing all articles using Big5 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, cjk

I'm writing a website with some articles for a Chinese audience. On the page that lists the articles I would like it to list the title and a small proportion of the article. However, the articles are encoded in a mixture of different Big5 encodings. Don't ask me why - that's what I got - so I can't guarantee the number of bytes each character takes to encode.

How can I then trim down the string to show only a small proportion of the article, without chopping off the bytes needed to encode a character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're certain that you won't have any characters outside of the BMP then you can convert the text to UCS-2 and then slice on an even boundary.